# Phantomjs *.png img not rendering

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use phantomjs 1.9.7. My goal is to render pdf from html template via phantomjs. On page 
I have next code:

```
   <body>
        <div id="page" >

       <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header" >
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/my-logo.png" width="1000" height="85" border="0" alt=""></div>
   </div>
```

path to img is correct but it is not displayed in generated pdf, please help.

Comment: Is it displayed when you render as png?

Comment: No, not displayed, maybe my approach is invalid ?

Comment: You may need to wait a little before rendering if the page (or the element) is dynamically created.

Comment: Please register to the [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Don't forget to include the results in the question. Have you tried to wait before rendering? `setTimeout(function(){page.render("screen.png");}, 5000);`.

Answer (score 0):

I used setTimeout method, it works:

```
setTimeout(function() {

        _page.render(name, function () {
            cb(null, name);
        });
    }, 2000);
```

Also I should notice that I add images to template in js code then I do actually a render.
Now all work. Thanks guys for help!